# Securing connection to a website with HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https

I want to use HTTPS on my website. Should I take care of something else while building the website in order to secure my website with HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Take care of resources (images, css, ajax requests) : they must start with "https://" (or, at least "//") to avoid mixed content errors.

After that, just ensure that all http request are redirected to https.